# Entity Framework Include in Where Subquery

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I believe I'm missing something obvious here and I can not figure it out. I receieve the exception :

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Privilege] Include[Privilege,PrivilegeType](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Privilege], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[Privilege,PrivilegeType]])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

When I run this EF query:

```
return _context.Categories.Where(c =>
             _context.Privileges
               .Include(p => p.PrivilegeType)
              .Where(p => p.PrivilegeType.Code == "code").Any()).ToList();
```

The end result I'm after is to determine if a user has a privilege based on the categoryId. At the moment, I have omitted the conditions in the Any() clause to simplify the statement.

Is this type of query possible?

**Edit:**
Here is the FulentApi configuration:

```
public class PrivilegeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Privilege>
{
    public PrivilegeConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("ObjectPrivileges");

        HasKey(p => new { p.ObjectTypeId, p.ObjectId, p.PrivilegeTypeId });

        Property(p => p.ObjectTypeId)
            .HasColumnName("ObjectType")
            .HasMaxLength(2);

        Property(p => p.PrivilegeTypeId)
            .HasColumnName("PrivilegeID")
            .IsRequired();

        HasRequired(p => p.PrivilegeType);
    }
}

 public class PrivilegeTypeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<PrivilegeType>
{
    public PrivilegeTypeConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("PrivilegeType");

        HasKey(p => p.PrivilegeTypeId);

        Property(p => p.PrivilegeTypeId)
            .HasColumnName("PrivilegeID");

        Property(p => p.ObjectTypeId)
            .HasColumnName("ObjectType")
            .HasMaxLength(2);

        Property(p => p.Code)
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        Property(p => p.Description)
            .HasMaxLength(255);
    }
}
```

**Edit 2:**

The where condition is something I would like to drop into the query to limit the amount of records that will come back. I'm updating a legacy database and trying to match what they currently already have in place to keep it as close to possible.

Here is the full query I am attemping:

```
var query = _context.Categories.AsQueryable();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(privilege))
        query = query.Where(c => (!_context.Privileges
         .Include(p => p.PrivilegeType)
         .Any(p => p.PrivilegeValue == 1
            && p.PrivilegeType.Code == privilege
            && p.ObjectTypeId == objectTypeId
            && p.ObjectId == c.CategoryId))
         ||
         _context.Privileges
             .Include(p => p.PrivilegeType)
             .Any(p => p.PrivilegeValue == 1
                 && p.PrivilegeType.Code == privilege
                 && p.ObjectTypeId == objectTypeId
                 && p.ObjectId == c.CategoryId
                 && (p.UserId == userId || _context.UserGroups.Select(ug => ug.UserID).Contains(userId))));
```

Here is the SQL representation of what I would like to do:

```
SELECT * FROM Categories WHERE(
(NOT EXISTS 

    (
        SELECT P.ObjectType 
        FROM ObjectPrivileges P 
            INNER JOIN PrivilegeType PT ON P.PrivilegeID = PT.PrivilegeID 
        WHERE 
            (
                P.PrivilegeValue > 0 
                AND PT.Code ='code' 
                AND P.ObjectType = 'SELECT'  
                AND P.ObjectID = 1 -- CategoryId
            )
    )
) OR

EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT P.ObjectType 
        FROM ObjectPrivileges P 
            INNER JOIN PrivilegeType PT ON P.PrivilegeID = PT.PrivilegeID 
        WHERE 
            (
                P.PrivilegeValue > 0 
                AND PT.Code = 'code' 
                AND P.ObjectType = 'SELECT' 
                AND P.ObjectID = 1 -- CategoryId
                AND (P.UserID = 57 OR P.GroupID IN (SELECT GroupID FROM Group_User WHERE UserID = 57))
            )
    ))
```

Comment: Have you mapped the foreign key relationship?  Could you show us your entity code and mapping code?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `c` any where in your lambda?

Comment: @RobertPetz I added the mapping code in my edit.

Comment: Why are you using `_context.Privileges` in the `Where()` expression? You can't do that like this, what do you want that to do? Perhaps try finding a tutorial about querying related entities?

Comment: @dcg I do use it, it would be in the Any() part of the expression. I omitted that to keep it simple.

Comment: @CodeCaster I would like to eventually use a generic subquery hitting the privileges table and passing in the Id off of the main query for tables other than categories.

Comment: Yeah so there is no relation between the two according to Entity Framework? Then you'll have to manually join the two in your `Where()`.

Comment: @CodeCaster Correct, there is not a relationship between privileges and categories. What's strange is that if I removed the include() it works. Not sure why.

Comment: @InvaderZim I'm confused your query shows a relationship of Privileges.ObjectId equaling Categories.CategoryId?

Comment: @RobertPetz Correct, they have a generic privilege table setup for tables other than Categories. The ObjectId field on the Privileges table is a int column that points (with no defined relationship) to the primary key of another table's record they want to restrict access to.

Comment: @InvaderZim - a relationship exists then, it is just a conditional relationship.  You can absolutely map that as a relationship in EF so long as you perform the correct conditions in your where clauses.  A foreign key does not have to actually exist in the database for your Linq queries to utilize a Entity Mapping between those two entities

Comment: @RobertPetz Oh, good to know! How would you suggest I do this in this case, but also keep it open to use tables other than categories?

Comment: Ok, I verified that the query does work. The Not exists part excludes the record from the result set if the record has a privilege assigned, and then if the user belongs to to the privilege or is in the group assigned to the privilege, it is added back in on the other part after the OR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems:

1. As said in the comments, there's no foreign key relationship between `Category` and `Privilege`. There is a soft relationship: `Privilege.ObjectID` points to *a* primary key of *a* table. The problem is that your subquery doesn't relate categories and privileges, because `CategoryID` isn't used. The condition is either true or false for *any* category.
2. `Include` only works if it populates navigation properties of entities in the query result. In other words, `Privileges.Include(p => p.PrivilegeType)` is only effective if `Privileges` are returned. Apart from that, `Include`s can't be filtered so they can't be used as filter conditions.

So the first thing to do is: match `CategoryID`. Any query of this nature should look like ...

```
_context.Categories
        .Where(c => !_context.Privileges
                             .Any(p => p.ObjectId == c.CategoryId
                                    && ...))
```

The second this is to use `PrivilegeType` in a way that allows it to be filtered: `p.PrivilegeType.Code == "code"`.

Applying these fixes, the entire query will look like this:

```
var userId = 57;
return _context.Categories
   .Where(c => 
       !_context.Privileges
                .Any(p => p.ObjectId == c.CategoryId
                       && p.PrivilegeValue > 0
                       && p.PrivilegeType.Code == "code"
                       && p.ObjectType = 'SELECT')
     || _context.Privileges
                .Any(p => p.ObjectId == c.CategoryId
                       && p.PrivilegeValue > 0
                       && p.PrivilegeType.Code == "code"
                       && p.ObjectType = 'SELECT'
                       && (p.UserId == userId
                             || _context.GroupUsers
                                        .Any(gu => gu.UserId == userId
                                                && gu.GroupID == p.GroupID)))
         );
```

Comment: Awesome, this worked like a charm! I didn't realize includes couldn't be used in the where clause. I'm still wrapping my head around EF, thanks for detailed answer.

Comment: Random side question, would you know of a good way to reuse this where condition for other entities, not just for categories but for table "A", "B", "C" etc?

Comment: You'll have to build the expressions in a generic method that uses the generic type parameter to build the parameter part of the lambda expression. You better ask a new question if you need more specific help here.

Answer (score 0):

Your current query is not actually performing any kind of filtering related to the different entities:

```
return _context.Categories.Where(c =>
               _context.Privileges
               .Include(p => p.PrivilegeType)
               Where(p => p.PrivilegeType.Code == "code").Any()).ToList();
```

This code will go to the database and get **all `Categories` in the database** if there are any `Privilege` entities in the database with a `PrivilegeType.Code` value of `code`.  This doesn't filter anything, it just returns **all** `Categories`.

Also as mentioned in the comments by @dcg you are not using the `c` variable in your first lambda expression, which I do believe is the cause of the actual exception you are receiving as a C# object (in this case `_context`) cannot be passed into a where expression like that.

The resolution would be this:

```
_context.Categories.Where(c => c.Privileges.Any(p => p.PrivilegeType.Code == "code")).ToList();
```

This assumes you have a foreign key relationship between `Categories` and `Privileges`.  If you do not, then you will need to restructure how those two tables are related or provide more details on what you are attempting to join the two entities using.

EDIT:

After your clarification in your post yes the above query is what you are looking for, but you need to actually map a relationship between your `Categories` and `Privileges` entities.  On your `Categories` entity mapping configuration do this:

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int PrivilegeId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Privilege> Privilege { get; set; }
}

public class Privilege
{
    public int PrivilegeId { get; set; }
    public int ObjectId { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Category>
{
    public CategoryMap()
    {
        ToTable("Categories");
        HasKey(x => x.CategoryId);

        HasMany(x => x.Privilege)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(x =>
            {
                x.MapLeftKey(nameof(Category.PrivilegeId));
                x.MapRightKey(nameof(Privilege.ObjectId));
            });
    }
}

public class PrivilegeMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Privilege>
{
    public PrivilegeMap()
    {
        ToTable("Categories");
        HasKey(x => x.PrivilegeId);
    }
}
```

This will allow you to define a relationship that is 1-* between Category and Privilege, without requiring that Privilege actually has any kind of relationship back to Category.  You will be able to write complex queries like this as a result.

EDIT:

I have attempted to recreate your SQL query (though I had to build my own local context from the structures of your above code, it may not be exactly accurate)

I *believe* that this will generate the same result set as your query.  It may not generate the same SQL, but the results should be the same.

```
public IQueryable<Category> Query(int userId)
{
    var db = new Context();

    var groupUsers = db.GroupUsers.Where(x => x.UserId == userId).Select(gu => gu.GroupId);

    var first = db.Privileges
        .Join(db.PrivilegeTypes, p => p.PrivilegeTypeId, pt => pt.PrivilegeTypeId, (p, pt) => new { P = p, PT = pt })
        .Where(join => join.P.PrivilegeValue > 0 &&
                        join.PT.Code == "code" &&
                        join.P.ObjectTypeId == "SELECT" &&
                        join.P.ObjectTypeId == "1");

    var second = first.Where(join => join.P.UserId == userId || groupUsers.Contains(join.P.UserId));

    return db.Categories.Where(c => first.All(join => join.P.ObjectId != c.CategoryId) ||
                                    second.Any(join => join.P.ObjectId == c.CategoryId));
}

Query(57); // Look up UserID 57
```

Comment: Tanks for the quick reply! I updated my question above with more detail.

Comment: @InvaderZim I updated my answer - I didn't run this against a database directly so if there are any runtime errors let me know, but it should point you in the correct direction to do what you are trying to do

Comment: Hmm, I understand the FulentApi to create the virtual relationship between the two entities, thank you for showing me how to do that; however, I'm struggling with how to translate the SQL query above into what I need. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @InvaderZim I updated my answer with what I believe will recreate your query - if doesn't it should at least give you the appropriate jump start.  Note that I'm not using the relationship that my answer originally stated - this is because your query is quite odd in nature and it doesn't really lend itself to that relationship

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and effort into helping me. The query you came up with would have worked if the objectId in the join wasn't static, but I needed the category Id there from category table. GertzArnold came up with a query that works for me :)